# format messed up while performing read xml file, append elements and write to a file

Tags: python, xml, dom, pretty-print

Using python, minidom..

I'm reading a pretty-formatted xml file, then adding elements before writing it back to a file again.

Everything works fine except the format of new added elements.

It looks like,

```
<previousTag>
   .. everything which was already in the xml file is correctly formatted.
   <addedTag1><addedTag2></addedTag2></addedTag1></previousTag>
```

whereas I want

```
<previousTag>
  <addedTag1>
     <addedTag2>
     </addedTag2>
  </addedTag1>
</previousTag>
```

I've tried to convert the whole thing to prettyxml using toprettyxml().
But then it looks like

```
<previousTag>
  ..so many unwanted whitespaces inbetween already existing tags..
  <addedTag1>
      <addedTag2>
      </addedTag2>
  </addedTag1>
  ..whitespaces..
</previousTag>
```

Comment: This guy has a good method for fixing the whitespace madness of toprettyxml(): 
http://ronrothman.com/public/leftbraned/xml-dom-minidom-toprettyxml-and-silly-whitespace/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either strip the whitespace yourself, or inform your parser to do it for you (if possible).

I've spent a few minutes trying to look for parser configuration options available using minidom looked at the source code and to be honest, I can't be bothered to look any further as it's well documented using `lxml.etree`:

```
from lxml import etree

sample = """
<previousTag>
  <previousSubElement1>Foo</previousSubElement1>
  <previousSubElement2>Bar</previousSubElement2>
</previousTag>
"""

doc = etree.XML(sample,etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))
addedTag1 = doc.makeelement('addedTag1')
addedTag2 = doc.makeelement('addedTag2')
addedTag2.text = "Baz"
addedTag1.append(addedTag2)
doc.append(addedTag1)

print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
```

Yielding:

```
<previousTag>
  <previousSubElement1>Foo</previousSubElement1>
  <previousSubElement2>Foo</previousSubElement2>
  <addedTag1>
    <addedTag2>Baz</addedTag2>
  </addedTag1>
</previousTag>
```

There are other ways of modifying XML objects with `lxml.etree`, this is just a quick and dirty example.